# Why isn't my Vue3 Router params working properly on redirect?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, quasar-framework, url-parameters, quasar

In my Vue3 Quasar project I have the following router link to redirect to a page and send a param in the url to be used in the page that is being redirected to.
If Ii enter the url with the param the page works normally, however if I redirect to it nothing works. What am I missing here? I jjust want to be able to show the route param and use it to perform an api call to show it's results.

Router link on first page:

My route in my routes.ts file is as follows:

```
{
  path: '/nextpage/:id',
  name: 'nextPage',
  component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
  children: [{ path: '', component: () => import('pages/DetailsPage.vue') }],
},
```

My nextPage:

```
<template>
  <q-page class="row items-center justify-evenly">
    {{ route.params.id }}
    <SomeComponent :data="store.details" />
  </q-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { computed, defineComponent, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { myStore} from 'stores/myStore';
import SomeComponent from 'components/SomeComponent .vue';

const store = myStore();

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'NextPage',
  components: { SomeComponent },
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    let currentRoute = computed(() => {
      return route.params; 
    });
    onMounted(() => {
      store.getInfo(route.params.id as string);
    });
    watch(currentRoute, () => {
      store.getInfo(route.params.id as string);
    });
    return { route, store };
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: There's a lot of vagueness here.  "I have the following router link to redirect to a page".  What link?  The problem is with a redirect, but I don't see where/how this redirect happens. When you say "nothing works", what do you mean exactly?  Is it a blank page? Is there an error? Is the UI wrong?  Also just to be clear, can you say which page is doing the redirecting and which page is being redirected to?  I assume NextPage is the page being redirect to, but where is the page being redirected from, and its code? Finally... show what the working URL looks like that you're testing with.